# Why is Chrome Web Developer tools not listing some JavaScript files as of version 27.0.1453.93?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

Our team uses Chrome Web Developer tools to debug JavaScript. As of yesterday when our browsers upgraded to Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93, the Sources section no longer lists all the JavaScript files. Does anyone know if this is a bug or if there is a setting? Some JavaScript files are still listed but I can't find the criteria for files being listed or not. I checked on an older Chrome Browser pointing to the same URL and all the files are listed. Anyone solved this?

Comment: Checked the Web Dev Network section and it shows certain js files downloading which are not listed under Sources?

Comment: Checked on 3 other machines and found the same anomaly.

Comment: have you tried the `content scripts` tab?

Comment: The Content Scripts tab seems to list only the scripts Chrome itself adds to the content downloaded. Is that right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you may have some javascript code that has been loaded dynamically. If it is the case, you should use the phrase

```
//@ sourceURL=foo.js
```

at the beginning of your javascript code. *foo.js* will be assigned it by debugger. And debugger will show it with that name.
chrome and firebug accept it, I am not sure about other browsers

Comment: Yes this seems to have fixed it. Thanks.